# Utilizing jquery.tablesorter with a jquery.tmpl generated table

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, knockout.js

I have a table that is dynamically generated wit jquery.tmpl from a KnockoutJS observableArray viewModel.  After the initial binding, I also apply tablesorter to the table id to get sorting.

As I would "expect" whenever an item is removed (or added to) the viewModel, the table updates, but after the update tablesorter is not functional unless I again call `$("#id").tablesorter();`.

Is there a best practice here for using both jQuery.tablesorter with KnockoutJS?  Is there a better plugin to use here?  Obviously what I'm doing works, but I wonder if I'm missing something simple that would be more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than call **$("#id").tablesorter()** each time, you can call **$("#id").trigger("update")**.

This seems to be the preferred way to let tablesorter know that there is new data to consider based on the [docs](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html).

If you wanted to get a little fancier with it, you could create a custom binding for your table that gets called any time that your observableArray changes.

Would look like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.triggerUpdate = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); //need to just access the observable to create the subscription
        $(element).trigger("update");
    }
}
```

Then, you would put this on your table like:

```
<table id="mytable" data-bind="triggerUpdate: items">
```